# Windows Service using VB.Net, Not working

Tags: vb.net, service

Here is what I did:

1. Created a `Windows Service` using the online guide on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a.aspx). That writes events into the `EventLog`
2. Installed the service using `installutil.exe`, The service name pops up in `services.msc`
3. I start the service manually to find that the `Start` log gets written in the `EventLog`

Now the problem:

The `Timer`'s `Tick` method has been set to 10000 millisecond, so that after every 10 seconds, the `EventLog` gets an entry. This does not happen. Just the `Start` log is visible. When I stop, the `Stop` log gets written.

The `Timer` is enabled, code is checked, double checked, triple checked, but I don't know what the problem is. I tried finding every where, but not much info is available about `Windows Service` using VB.Net

This is my first time coding a service, and have no experience in doing so. Please help me find the bug out.

[The Source Code](https://mega.co.nz/#F!uUpClRgK!egKf8hkI6_NSxmiFKOlfWA)

---

I tried this in the `Timer`'s `Tick` event:

```
Try
        Dim i As Integer = 1 
        evlwe("Tick " & i)
        i += 1      'Thanks for reminding about this @Plutonix and @Matt Wilko
    Catch ex As Exception
        evlwe("Error! " & ex.Message)
    End Try
```

But still doesn't work. No "Tick 1" nor "Error!" gets added in the "MyNewLog" folder under Event Viewer. Just the start and stop.

Another thing I forgot to mention in the OP is that I am manually starting this service from the `Services.msc` app in windows. Is that what I am doing wrong?

Now I'm trying to check if there is any problem in the starting and stopping of the `Timer`, by using `Try Catch` in the `Start` and `Stop` events of the `Service`.

Comment: Please put the relevant code within your post in the future as people are more likely to help you (and it prevents link rot) :-)

Comment: What timer are you using?  There are several available.  If you are using `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, it will _not work_ in a Windows service.  Use one of the others.

Comment: Are you sure? because everywhere i see- even for other languages, they use the same `timer` - "Drag and drop the `timer` control from the toolbox..."

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Dude, you were correct. `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` wouldn't work with `Windows Services`. We need to create a `System.Timers` `Timer`. Because, `Windows Services` cannot interact with `Form`s and hence the drag and drop `Timer` from the design tab wouldn't work. Ref [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the `Timer` that I used wouldn't work with `Services` because this type of `Timer` belongs to the `System.Windows.Forms` class, and `Services` cannot use / cannot interact with the desktop. i.e They cannot use windows to display content. Hence, `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` cannot work with `Services`.

Even the summary for this type of `Timer` as described in Visual Studio says this:

```
Public Class Timer
      Inherits System.ComponentModel.Component
 Member of System.Windows.Forms
Summary:
Implements a timer that raises an event at user-defined intervals. This timer is 
optimized for use in Windows Forms applications and must be used in a window.
```

The correct and usable way is to create a `System.Timers` instance. More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1).

Thanks [@Chris Dunaway](https://stackoverflow.com/users/70104/chris-dunaway) for pointing in the right direction. And everyone else for taking effort in helping me.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible an error is being thrown and swallowed:

In the tick event you are concatenate a string with an integer using '+', this can't be done.

In VB you use `&` to concatenate strings, or use `i.ToString` or better still switch `Option Strict On` and this will not compile forcing you to do one of the fixes mentioned.

Solution

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    evlwe("Tick " & i) 'Use & for string concat, evlwe("Tick " + i) won't work
End Sub
```

You should also think about some error handling, and then log the error in the event log.

Comment: it looks like `i` will always be zero too

Comment: @Plutonix - Indeed; I thought I would leave the OP to find that one out for themselves...